# Emscripten passing callback from C - Runtime.getFuncWrapper - Runtime is not defined

Tags: emscripten

I am trying to run [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/aknuds1/533f7b228aa46e9ee4c8) but without having the compile parameters. My attempt:

```cpp
// file: pass_array.cpp
#include <cstdio>

extern "C" {
    extern void initialize(void (*callback)(float*));
}

void callback(float* output)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        output[i] = i+1;
    }
    printf("Callback was invoked\n");
}

int main()
{
    initialize(&callback);
    return 0;
}
```

```js
// file: pass_array_library.js
// "use strict";

var LibraryTst = {
  initialize: function (callback) {
    callback = Runtime.getFuncWrapper(callback, 'vi') // error here
    var numBytes = 2 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT
    var ptr = Module._malloc(numBytes)

    try {
      callback(ptr)

      console.log('Callback filled buffer like so:')
      var i = 0
      for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        console.log(HEAPF32[(ptr/Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT)+i])
      }
    }
    finally {
      Module._free(ptr)
    }
  },
}

mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, LibraryTst)
```

Compile:

```
emcc -O1 -Wall -Werror --bind -o pass_array.html --js-library pass_array_library.js pass_array.cpp
```

When I open the html, I get

```
pass_array.html:1 exception thrown: ReferenceError: Runtime is not defined,ReferenceError: Runtime is not defined
    at _initialize (http://0.0.0.0:8000/pass_array.js:2119:7)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, looking at the [FAQ](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/FAQ.html#why-does-runtime-no-longer-exist-why-do-i-get-an-error-trying-to-access-runtime-something), the `Runtime` object has disappeared, and instead the function `getFuncWrapper` should be called directly:

```js
    callback = getFuncWrapper(callback, 'vi');
```

But the library function `getFuncWrapper` must also be explicitly exported. It must be prefixed with `$`. There are two options. Either pass on the command-line:

```
emcc --bind -o pass_array.html --js-library pass_array_library.js \
  -s DEFAULT_LIBRARY_FUNCS_TO_INCLUDE=[\$getFuncWrapper] pass_array.cpp
```

(`$` escaped here for bash)

Or, better, declared as a dependency of the library:

```js
var LibraryTst = {
  initialize: function (callback) { ... },
  initialize__deps: ['$getFuncWrapper'],  // !
}
```